# Print "multiple" if multiple values selected from checkbox

Tags: angularjs

If user selects more than one checkbox then it should print "multiple values". Now it's showing all the values which user selects. I am trying if else condition with array.length (if array.length> 1) but its not working in my case. Below is HTML and AngularJS code

```
<div class="btn-group acc-vel-env">
                <div class="btn-group metric-dropdown" uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
                  <button id="metricDropdown" type="button" class="btn" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
                     {{metricObject.selectedMetrics.toString().toUpperCase()}}<span class="caret"></span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu metric-dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu"
                        aria-labelledby="metricDropdown" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
                        <li ng-repeat="metricItem in metricObject.metricGroups">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="{{metricItem.id}}" name="{{metricItem.name}}" 
                                    ng-checked="metricObject.selectedMetrics.indexOf(metricItem.id) > -1"
                                    ng-value="metricItem.id" ng-click="setSelectedMetrics(metricItem.id)"> 
                                    <label for="{{metricItem.id}}">{{metricItem.name}}</label>
                            </div>
```

Angular JS:-

```
      if(metricId === 'all'){
        mId = $scope.metricObject.selectedMetrics.indexOf(metricId);
        $scope.metricObject.selectedMetrics = [];

        if (mId > -1) {
            $scope.metricObject.selectedMetrics = [];
            $scope.metricObject.selectedMetrics.push('c1');

        }
        else {
            $.each($scope.metricObject.metricGroups, function(i,metricObj){
                $scope.metricObject.selectedMetrics.push(metricObj.id);
            });
        }
    } 

    else {
        mId = $scope.metricObject.selectedMetrics.indexOf(metricId);            
        if (mId > -1) {
            $scope.metricObject.selectedMetrics.splice(mId, 1);
        } else {
            $scope.metricObject.selectedMetrics.push(metricId);
        }
    }

    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.showTimeSeries(metricId);
    });
}
```

Comment: `angular` tag is for Angular 2+.

Comment: It's not really easy to understand your Code if you just show a part of a function in js. Is this the $scope.setSelectedMetrics-function?

Comment: SelectedMetrics is an object which is being called from backend